# Vagrant: Cannot access Rails server via localhost:8080

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vagrant, ubuntu-14.04, portforwarding

My `Vagrantfile` contains:

```
config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 8080
```

`vagrant up` reports:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 3000 => 8080 (adapter 1)
...
```

Using a non-privileged user (`deploy') I run`rails server` which reports what you'd expect:

```
Booting WEBrick => Rails 4.2.5 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
[2015-12-01 13:34:41] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1638 port=3000
```

Inside of the vagrant vm `$ netstat -ntlp` reports:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1638/ruby
```

so I know that the Rails server is definitely listening on port 3000

When I browse to http://localhost:8080 on my host machine (OS X) I get an `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.

I've tried stopping/starting the vm, reloading it, etc. Am I missing something obvious?

Thank you in advance

Comment: can you check if nothing is running from your host on port 8080 ? most likely a process has already bound the port so it cannot be used by vagrant. I dont know if in such case vagrant up reports an error or not

Comment: @FrédéricHenri I've changed the port (8080) to a number of other values and the behavior is the same. Nothing on the host is using the ports I've tried.

Comment: @RobertJoseph What's the output when running `curl -I http://localhost:3000/` in the guest VM?

Comment: @FrédéricHenri Exactly what I'd expect: https://goo.gl/Cnpcij (gist)

Comment: you might have firewall rules on your guest that prevent to reach port 3000 from external

Comment: Can you please share the complete vagrant file and rails development log.

Comment: Long reach, but did you resolve this issue? I am having the exact same problem, have been working on it all morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `/etc/hosts`, associate 0.0.0.0 with localhost. When a service is listening on 0.0.0.0 this means the service is listening on all the configured network interfaces, when listening on 127.0.0.1 the service is only bound to the loopback interface (only available on the local machine).

In `/etc/hosts` on the guest machine, replace `127.0.0.1 localhost` with `0.0.0.0 localhost`.

Then restart the rails server.

Answer (score 3):

Try starting rails with `rails server -b 0.0.0.0`